# Selenium c# System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to create a crawler and scraper with selenium. I using the Previews version of **Selenium.Support**, **Selenium.WebDriver** and **Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver** (chrome 83).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.0.0-alpha05" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.0.0-alpha05" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="83.0.4103.1400-beta" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and my code:

```
protected virtual IWebDriver WebDriverInitialize()
    {
        return IWebDriver Driver ?? (Driver = new ChromeDriver());
    }

    public void CrawlerInitializer()
    {
        var webDriver = WebDriverInitialize();
       webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyCrawler crawler = new MyCrawler();
            crawler.CrawlerInitializer();

            Console.WriteLine("Finish");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

but give me an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'session not created: This version
>   of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

I'm using chrome 83 why given this error?

Comment: refer this https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.14/ . There is no beta version

Comment: I downloaded and replaced new chromedriver.exe with old but still, give me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Chrome beta - 83. Whenever the tests executes, It requires the default chrome version as 83 and not the beta version.

Please check.

Comment: I downloaded version 83 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.14/ and replaced new chromedriver.exe with old but still, give me the same error

Comment: I was talking about Chrome browser. If it is beta version of browser, than your chromedriver.exe wont find it.

Comment: yeah update my browser to last stable (81.0.4044) version and set selenium web driver to the same version, now work fine